Quinoa with vinegar

Solve on Penpa+
Across
1. Bravo! First-rate type of code you texted back... It reveals almost nothing! (5)
5. Standard for Brits but not for the French or for Germans, who cut quantity in half (6)
9. Cyclops and Storm both have one (3)
10. Arab paramilitaries faced with counter intelligence? (5)
14. Hack a complex backend with GNOME terminal (3)
15. Principally, sensible and mature (4)
16. Russian guy attending NYU rickrolled (4)
17. Disagreement is a necessary and sufficient condition for pursuing ending in court (4)
20. Conspiracy theorists wait for their turn to come soon on the radio (5)
21. Lake that's mysteriously frightening, according to hearsay (4)
23. Madagascan native feathered biped has two hands on the appropriate sides (5)
26. Pressurised container for bit of kefir, say (3)
27. Dish of cold quinoa, mixed with hint of vinegar (3,2,3)
30. City Gentlemen's Quarterly: "Beer brewed with small amount of hops? Excellent!" (8)
32. The setter is now going to do what the Beastie Boys were licensed to (3)
33. Pose as an adult (5)
34. Service station's crew recalled spilling drop of petrol (4)
35. Stop gold miners' train in 30 across, briefly (5)
39. Advantages for people being paid (4)
42. Great characters of Santana, Lifeson, Iommi, Townshend and Slash (4)
44. A bitter rivalry endlessly revisited in soccer's governing body (4, abbr.)
46. Decide story's central point (3)
47. Quarterback attends addict group after drinking a port (5)
48. Israeli shooter that's up with almost nothing (3)
49. Question in connection with Father Christmas's uninitiated carrier (6)
50. One leaving ship with only 50% of water after circling around Arabian Peninsula (5)
Down
1. Rhythm guitarist Paul kicked out of the band of another? (4)
2. Spain included in official setting of Finding Nemo? (4)
3. Reported ingredient in fondue: Spiritual life forces (3)
4. After wizard cut Sofia's bread, it hovers above the ground! (6)
6. People with it are humorous and clever with it (3)
7. Top country singer (4)
8. One with little experience cheers Jafe being ejected from Carnival site (4)
11. ...And that concludes our proof – somewhat inadequate, looking back (3, abbr.)
12. Manufacturer of old aircraft and old cars (7)
13. A dog barking after MI6 employee in Chinese city (7)
18. Anchorman Burgundy supports independent press (4)
19. Slovene university graduates gutlessly giving punches (5)
21. Better containers for 19 down in possession of East European (7)
22. Canadian city worker's final words, possibly after snorting a line (7)
24. Release African beast that's swallowed a bee on the way up (5)
25. Parisian's way to have second thoughts? (3)
28. Healthcare reform described by current affairs centre (3, abbr.)
29. I'm surprised because of that, really (2,2)
31. Make beloved Game Boy equipped with chip from AMD (6)
36. Opening delayed in festive gathering serving seaweed? (4)
37. Immediately articulate, without being allowed to finish (4)
38. Street market surrounding northern end of Union Square (3)
40. Republican with entirely crushing defeat (4)
41. Commotion in prison (4)
43. Cry from horned figure, one worshipped in parts of Ancient Syria, but not all (3)
45. Leading figures in administration attacked! Assault and battery? (3)

Finished Grid:

 

Note: I am not entirely convinced my wordplays were the intended for 29 down and 40 down.
ACROSS

 1. BURQA - B [bravo] + (A + QR + U)<
 5. QWERTY - WER [who in German] in Q_TY
 9. EYE - ddef
 10. IRAQI - IRA + IQ<
 14. AXE - A + _X + _E
 15. SAGE (&lit) - S_ + AGE
 16. YURI - _YU RI_
 17. TIFF - IFF [if and only if, a necessary and sufficient condition in mathematical proofs] + _T
 20. QANON - "QUEUE ANON"
 21. ERIE - "EERIE"
 23. LEMUR - EMU + L_R [hands on appropriate sides, clever!]
 26. KEG - K_ + EG [e.g.]
 27. COQ AU VIN - C [cold] + QUINOA* + V_
 30. GQEBERHA - GQ + BEER* + H_ + A [excellent]
 32. ILL - ddef [I'LL and ILL]
 33. ASANA [yoga pose] - AS + AN + A
 34. ESSO - (-p)OSSE<
 35. PAUSE - (AU + _S) in P.E. [Port Elizabeth was old name for 30 across]
 39. PROS - ddef.
 42. SLIT - S_ L_ I_ T_
 43. BAA - BAA(-l)
 44. UEFA - (A + FEU(-d))<
 46. OPT - _O_ + PT
 47. AQABA - (QB + A [drinking a]) in AA
 48. UZI - U [up] + ZI(-p) [almost nothing]
 49. QANTAS - Q + (-s)ANTAS
 50. QATAR - (RAT + AQ(-ua))<

DOWN

 1. BEAT - BEAT(-les) [LES Paul removed from band of Paul McCartney]
 2. REEF - REF + E [Spain, as España]
 3. QIS - "CHEESE"
 4. MAGLEV - MAG(-e) + LEV [currency of Bulgaria, whose capital is Sofia]
 6. WIT - W [with] + IT
 7. ENYA - (-k)ENYA [top is used to indicate remove top of]
 8. TYRO - TY [cheers] + R(-i)O [Rio losing I, as Jafe is writer]
 11. QED - (_DEQ_)<
 12. JUNKERS - ddef.
 13. QINGDAO - (A DOG)* + Q [character in James Bond] + IN
 18. IRON - RON [Burgundy] + I [Independent]
 19. SLUGS - SL + U + G_S
 21. ECLIPSE - CLIPS [container for slugs, as in bullets] + EE
 22. IQALUIT - I QUIT + A L
 24. UNBAG - (GNU + A + B)<
 25. RUE - ddef
 28. ACA - AC [current] + A [affairs centre]
 29. AH SO - AH [I'm surprised] + SO [because of that], def. is "really?"
 31. ENDEAR - ENDER [boy from Ender's Game] + A_ [chip from AMD]  (h/t Narushiteli...thanks!)
 36. ALGA - (-g)AL(+G)A [opening delayed in word]
 37. STAT - STAT(-e)
 38. SUQ - U_ + SQ
 40. ROUT - R + OUT [entirely, as in out-and-out]
 41. STIR - ddef. [stir is slang for prison]
 45. AAA - A_ A_ A_ [type of battery]

Theme notes:

 There are a lot of Qs in here, which reminds me of a puzzle of Jafe's I solved which was rich in Js. Lots of fun!


31d -- the reference is to rot13(Raqre'f Tnzr) by rot13(Befba Fpbgg Pneq) (link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game ) with the chip from AMD referring to chipping off the start letter.

not only are there {n ybg bs df, ohg abar bs gurz ner sbyybjrq (nf jbhyq or rkcrpgrq) ol n h}

And the rot13(D'f fbyir gur gjryir-dhrraf ceboyrz). Well, not quite ... ;)

Nice work! I had a slightly different idea for 29d, rot13(bu fb vzcbegnag ~ ernyyl vzcbegnag), but yours works just as well.

@MOehm Man, wish I had thought of that!
